# Android application for storage contacts

Tags: java, android

I started learning Android programming, and have a task like this:

Create Android app in which you'll implement these functionalities:

Make data storage which will keep certain contact's info. (file on SD card or database).
That file on sd card/database should contain data in the form of phone numbers of certain persons.
Display all elements of the file that you created in List View component.
Click on certain element in list (contact) should send sms to selected his number from storage.

I done some code, mostly going by the book with this task, but I have problem when I should set contact's Id, Name and Phone Number with certain set methods.

I defined Contact class in Contact.java with constructors, set and get methods:

```
package com.example.zadatak1;

public class Contact {

    int id;
    String name;
    String phone;

    public Contact(){

    }

    public Contact(int id, String name, String phone){
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
        this.phone=phone;
    }

    public Contact(String name, String phone){
        this.name=name;
        this.phone=phone;
    }

    public int getID(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setID(int id){
        this.id=id;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }

    public String getPhone(){
        return this.phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone){
        this.phone=phone;
    }

}
```

Problem is in Handler.java lines at the end of file:

```
package com.example.zadatak1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class Handler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "databaseContact";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "contacts";
    private static final String ID = "id";
    private static final String NAME = "name";
    private static final String PHONE = "phone_number";

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public Handler(Context context){
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }



@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String CREATE_CONTACTS = "CREATE_TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + NAME + "TEXT," + PHONE + "TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

void addContact(Contact contact){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(NAME, contact.getName());
    values.put(PHONE, contact.getPhone());

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();

}

    Contact getContact(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{ID,NAME,PHONE}, NAME, new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor!=null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));

    return contact;

    }

    public List<Contact> getAllContacts(){
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME+ " ORDER BY " + NAME + "ASC";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        return contactList;
    }

        Contact contact = new Contact ();
        contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        contact.setPhone(cursor.getString(2));

}
```

For the "SetID", "setName" and "setPhone" I got errors:
"Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on tokens, AnnotationName expected 
     instead
    - Syntax error on token "setID", Identifier expected after 
     this token
    - Syntax error on token "(", delete this token
    - Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens"

"Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on tokens, AnnotationName expected instead
    - Syntax error on token "setName", Identifier expected after this token
    - Syntax error, insert "Type VariableDeclaratorId" to complete 
     FormalParameterList"

"Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token "setPhone", Identifier expected after this token
    - Syntax error, insert "Type VariableDeclaratorId" to complete 
     FormalParameterList
    - Syntax error on tokens, AnnotationName expected instead"

Any help? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of code must be in some method, not just in the class body. Transfer this part of code in other needed place (I don't know logic, so I can't say where it should be):

```
Contact contact = new Contact ();
 contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
 contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
 contact.setPhone(cursor.getString(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

1) you did not use getters and setter proper place

2) you did not populate the array list

```
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();

        try {

            String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME+ " ORDER BY " + NAME + "ASC";
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        Contact contact = new Contact();
                        contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                        contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                        contact.setPhone(cursor.getString(2));

                        contactList.add(contact);

                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());

                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return contactList;
    }
```